# Shows multiple tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

[image: screenshot]

When I use TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE, overflowed tabs can be scrolled. But I want to show overflowed tabs below of visible tabs.

What's solution?

Now, I'm using two TabLayout to perform this, But in that case two tabs can select same time.

Comment: can you put some code or what are you doing ?

Comment: I added a screenshot.